# Focus not working in Chrome when set from FacesContext

Tags: jsf, facescontext

Am focusing element from server side using FacesContext like below,

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("focus", "addform:elementid");
```

XHtml look like below,

```
<h:form id="addform">
<t:panelGrid id="elementid" columns="1" width="280">
   <t:column colspan="4"></t:column>
</t:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Its working fine in IE 11. But not getting focused in Chrome Version 73.0.
Why am facing this issue in chrome.?

Comment: In IE11, does it also work without `fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("focus", "addform:elementid");`? Why do you think `fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("focus", "addform:elementid");` does something on client side?

Comment: No, In IE11 Focus working fine using `fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("focus", "addform:elementid");` The same code, but element not get focusing in Chrome.